# Validar números crescentes e decrescentes com regex

Tags: java, regex

Preciso criar um regex para validação de numeros crescente e decrecentes  conforme  o exemplo:

> Repetidos | crescente  | Decrescente
>   000000     |  012345    | 987654
>   111111     |  123456    | 543210
>   [09:30:16] William  Oliveira:

A validação de repetidos é essa  no regex `^(\w)1\{5,}$`

Comment: Sinceramente não entendi nada da sua pergunta. Edite e forneça melhor a explicação, senão fica complicado ajudar.

Comment: isso camarada, só deixe um pouco mais clara, também não consegui entender bem

Answer (score 3):

Você poderia fazer o seguinte: `^0*1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*$` para detectar crescentes, `^9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1*0*$`para decrescentes e `^0*|1*|2*|3*|4*|5*|6*|7*|8*|9*$` para repetidos, exemplo:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // match crescente
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches("^0*1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*$", "1368"));
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches("^0*1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*$", "9321"));

        // match decrescente
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches("^9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1*0*$", "1368"));
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches("^9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1*0*$", "9321"));

        // match repetidos
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches("^0*|1*|2*|3*|4*|5*|6*|7*|8*|9*$", "1111111111111"));
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches("^0*|1*|2*|3*|4*|5*|6*|7*|8*|9*$", "1111111111112"));
    }
}
```

que vai te devolver:

```
true
false

false
true

true
false
```

Comment: Obrigado, bruno me ajudou bastante ! :)